# How to install "psycopg2" properly in this situation

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-16.04, psycopg2, libpq

I'm installing `psycopg2` package for my project.

`pip install psycopg2`

then I got this error:

```
Collecting psycopg2
  Using cached https://pypi.tuna.tsinghua.edu.cn/packages/23/7e/93c325482c328619870b6cd09370f6dbe1148283daca65115cd63642e60f/psycopg2-2.8.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    /home/sl/anaconda3/envs/pd36/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'project_urls'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    Error: b'You need to install postgresql-server-dev-X.Y for building a server-side extension or libpq-dev for building a client-side application.\n'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-r7a1yqf1/psycopg2/
You are using pip version 9.0.1, however version 19.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

It said I need to install `libpq-dev`(Am I right?) before I install `psycopg2`, so I did

`sudo apt-get install libpq-dev`,

then it gave me

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libpq-dev : Depends: libpq5 (= 9.5.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but 10.5-1.pgdg16.04+1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

means I need to install `libpq5=9.5.17-0ubuntu0.16.04.1.`

HOWEVER, I can't install a version of 9.5.xx of libpq5 because my

postgresql database is up to 10.xx, and the installation of

`libpq5=9.5.xx` will reinstall my database to 9.5.xx, I can't let that

happen to my database. So finally, I can't install `psycopg2`.

How did that happen, how can I install psycopg2 properly, save me.

I've tried `apt-get install python-psycopg2` but I still can't import 
`psycopg2` in my project.

I'm using `python 3.6.5`, `ubuntu 16.04`.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get autoremove` to get rid of the `E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: @ApoorvGoyal Thanks, but that can't solve the problem.

Comment: Did you try running `sudo apt-get install libpq-dev` again?

Comment: @ApoorvGoyal Sure, it's still the same.

Comment: It seems like you installed postgresql from some repository other than the default system one.  Probably PGDG repo? Install libpq-dev from that same repository as you installed the server itself.